# Simplify $\frac{\partial T}{\partial s}\sin \psi + T\cos \psi \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial s} - \rho g = \rho \frac{Dv}{Dt}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I was given the following equation in some lecture notes:

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial s}\sin \psi + T\cos \psi \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial s} - \rho g = \rho \frac{Dv}{Dt}$$

It was then simplified to:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial s} (T \sin \psi) - \rho g = \rho \frac{Dv}{Dt}$$

How was this simplified? I would show my working so far but I'm completely lost on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use the product rule + chain rule

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial s}\left[T\sin \psi\right]=\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial s}\sin \psi +T\dfrac{\partial \sin \psi}{\partial s}=\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial s}\sin \psi +T\cos \psi \dfrac{\partial \psi}{\partial s}$$